# How to Select DISTINCT CONTACT of some Columns in Mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct, concat-ws

I have a join query that returns data like this :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | CONCAT_WS(',',D,E,F,G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | id2 | id3 | 14 | 15 | 14 | 16 | 14,15,14,16 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | ---------------------- |
| id5 | id6 | id7 | 14 | 15 | 17 | 16 | 14,15,17,16 |

I want the last column to only return unique values found in each record. For example, for the first record I want the last column to have values: `(14,15,16)` instead of `14,15,14,16`.

Comment: The obvious problem is there is no way of identifying FIRST record..Otherwse group_concat(distinct would be a goer..

Comment: I want to distinct all record but in sample just first record has duplicate number

Comment: group_concat will concat recoreds with eachother. I don't want merge records.

Answer (score 0):

sql is row based rather than column based so there is no function which can operate on columns in the way you want.

If you have a unique row identifier you could UNPIVOT using UNION which comes with an implicit distinct , group_concat and join for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

create table t
(id int , col1 int,col2 int,col3 int);

insert into t values
(1,1,2,3),(2,1,1,2),(3,3,3,3);

with cte as
(select id,col1 col from t
union
select id,col2 from t
union
select id,col3 from t
)
select *,gc
from t
join (select id,group_concat(col) gc from cte group by id) s on s.id = t.id
order by t.id;

+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 | id   | gc    | gc    |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    1 | 1,2,3 | 1,2,3 |
|    2 |    1 |    1 |    2 |    2 | 2,1   | 2,1   |
|    3 |    3 |    3 |    3 |    3 | 3     | 3     |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.023 sec)
```

if you don't have a unique row identifier you might get away with assigning one but there's no guarantee the rows output will be in the same order as the rows input.

```
with cte as
(select id,col1 col from t
union
select id,col2 from t
union
select id,col3 from t
),
cte1 as
(select id,row_number() over () rn from t)

select *,gc
from cte1 t
join (select id,group_concat(col) gc from cte group by id) s on s.id = t.id
order by t.id;
```

Both solution look poor performers but that's what happens with poorly built data.